# How to increment number with leading zeros in filename

Tags: python, bash, batch-rename

I have a set of files, not necessarily of the same extension. These files were created by a Python script that iterates over some files (say x.jpg, y.jpg, and z.jpg), and then numbers them with zero-padding so that the numbers are of length 7 characters (in this example, the filenames become `0000001 - x.jpg`, `0000002 - y.jpg`, and `0000003 - z.jpg`).

I now need a script (any language is fine, but Bash/zsh is preferred), that will increment these numbers by an argument. Thereby renaming all the files in the directory. For example, I'd like to call the program as (assuming a Shell script):

```
./rename.sh 5
```

The numbers in the final filenames should be padded to length 7, and it's guaranteed that there's no file initially whose number is 9999999. So the resulting files should be `0000006 - x.jpg`, `0000007.jpg`, `0000008.jpg`. It's guaranteed that all the files initially are incremental; that is, there are no gaps in the numbers.

I can't seem to do this easily at all in Bash, and it seems kind of like a chore even in Python. What's the best way to do this?

Edit: Okay so here are my efforts so far. I think the leading 0s are a problem, so I removed them using rename:

```
rename 's/^0*//' *
```

Now with just the numbers left, I'd ideally use a loop, something like this, but I'm not exactly familiar with the syntax and why this is wrong:

```
for file in "(*) - (*)" ; do mv "${file}" "$(($1+5)) - ${2}" ; done
```

The 5 there is just hard-coded, but I guess changing that to the first argument shouldn't be too big a deal. I can then use another loop to add the 0s back.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: So you start with file 1, add 5 to it and save it as file 6, so when you get to file 6 it actually contains file 1 now?

Comment: Be careful about the order in which you do things. If you have five files numbered from 1 through 5, for example, and your offset is 3, then if you start from the lowest number (1), you'll overwrite files 4 and 5 by renaming them, and end up with copies at the tail. Start at the tail and work backwards.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, it's just a batch renaming operation, with the numbers in the filenames incremented.

Comment: My question was intended to make you see a problem... you may need to run your loop backwards, i.e. counting down.

Comment: When coding this, I suggest writing in code that does a "dry run", so that you see what operations take place in what order, or to copy files with a new name to a separate directory. You want to help avoid problems with overwriting files in place.

Comment: Oh, you mean filename conflicts in case there's say, `001 - x.jpg` and `006 - x.jpg` initially? Right, I didn't think about that honestly. Okay, so I strip the leading 0s, go backwards, incrementing the numbers, and then add the 0s, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys, glob, re, os
# Get the offset at the first command-line argument
offset = int(sys.argv[1]) 

# Go through the list of files in the reverse order
for name in reversed(glob.glob('*.jpg')):
    # Extract the number and the rest of the name
    i, rest = re.findall("^(\d+)(.+)", name)[0]
    # Construct the new file name
    new_name = "{:07d}{}".format(int(i) + offset, rest)
    # Rename
    os.rename(name, new_name)
```